# not able to autowire in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-05-06 20:50:51.844 ERROR 2264 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field petRepo in com.pet.controller.PetController required a bean of type 'com.pet.repository.PetRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.pet.repository.PetRepository' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Can you post your code for PetController and PetRepository?

Answer (score 0):

try adding `@Repository` annotation to your repo class

```
   @Repository
    public interface PetRepository <T,ID extends Serializable> extends CrudRepository{
}
```